# Node js error in exceptions log. Unknown system error -116: Unknown system error -116, write

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, reactjs, ubuntu

I'm getting this error in exceptions.log file in node server. Could someone please explain what is this issue? we are using React JS v16.8.6, Node JS v8.14.0 running on Ubuntu v16.04 and we are doing a server side rendering.

```
    { error:
{ Error: Unknown system error -116: Unknown system error -116, write
    errno: -116,
    code: 'Unknown system error -116',
    syscall: 'write' },
level: 'error',
message: 'uncaughtException: Unknown system error -116: Unknown system error -116, write\nError: Unknown system error -116: Unknown system error -116, write',
stack: 'Error: Unknown system error -116: Unknown system error -116, write',
exception: true,
date: 'Sat Jun 29 2019 19:52:25 GMT+0530 (IST)',
process:
{ pid: 127,
    uid: 0,
    gid: 0,
    cwd: '/opt/maatran',
    execPath: '/usr/bin/node',
    version: 'v8.14.0',
    argv:
    [ '/usr/bin/node',
        '/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js',
        'start',
        'ecosystem.config.js' ],
    memoryUsage:
    { rss: 184356864,
        heapTotal: 154181632,
        heapUsed: 138251728,
        external: 929873 } },
os:
{ loadavg: [ 0.279296875, 0.14697265625, 0.099609375 ],
    uptime: 326785 },
trace: [],
timestamp: '2019-06-29T14:22:25.457Z' }
```

Thanks for the help. Please let me know if anyone needs more information.

Comment: Your error seems to have been thrown in the pm2 module. It may be worth checking this ticket: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3108  Two things on this: 1) it suggests updating the pm2 version in use. 2) It has a couple of diagnostic commands (e.g. `pm2 report`), the output of which might be worth posting here.